# How would I collapse rows based on a value in a column?

Tags: python, bash, tr

I’ll describe what I mean in more detail here.
Suppose I have a data sheet that looks like this:

```
+-----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+--------------+
|           | Person1 | Person2 | Person4 | Person4 | Person5 | Person6 |     City     |
+-----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+--------------+
| January   | -       |       - | Yes     |       - | Yes     | -       | SanFrancisco |
| Febuary   | Yes     |       - | -       |       - | -       | -       | SanFrancisco |
| March     | -       |       - | -       |       - | -       | -       | SanFrancisco |
| April     | -       |       - | -       |       - | -       | -       | NewYork      |
| May       | Yes     |       - | -       |       - | -       | -       | NewYork      |
| June      | -       |       - | -       |       - | -       | -       | NewYork      |
| July      | -       |       - | -       |       - | Yes     | -       | NewYork      |
| August    | -       |       - | -       |       - | -       | -       | NewYork      |
| September | -       |       - | -       |       - | -       | -       | Miami        |
| November  | -       |       - | -       |       - | -       | Yes     | Miami        |
| December  | -       |       - | -       |       - | -       | -       | Miami        |
+-----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+--------------+
```

Ignoring the ascii for stackoverflow formatting, It’s a simple spreadsheet that tracks 6 people based on what city they’ve been to in which months.

What I want to only know is, which people have visited which cities. Effectively condensing the list to look like this:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+--------------+
| Person1 | Person2 | Person4 | Person4 | Person5 | Person6 | City         |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+--------------+
| Yes     | -       | Yes     | -       | Yes     | -       | SanFrancisco |
| Yes     | -       | -       | -       | Yes     | -       | NewYork      |
| -       | -       | -       | -       | -       | Yes     | Miami        |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+--------------+
```

Each row is only ONE city, and contains which people have visited it. Is there  an optimum way to do this, or rather, is there some sort of tr(squeeze)/sed tool that already does this? If I had to code this, what would the optimum logic be?

Comment: Are the rows `January` and `SanFransisco` (for example) constant? I mean, can one person be in another city in January, or only in San Fransisco? Secondly, how is your data represented? Is it an excel sheet? A matrix? A 3d list?

Comment: They aren't constant, and their current location isnt noted.. it's just "famous cities you've visited" this year.

The list is a simple TSV or CSV in an excel sheet. I plan on operating on it with a python script. THe ascii characters are represented here for ease of viewing because SO does not have table paste for some reason

Comment: Excuse me for not understanding the problem well, but, what if, for example, person 6 has been to Miami in January? How will it be represented?

Comment: If your data is a CSV then show us a CSV, don't show us some other format that some other tool outputs when given a CSV as input. SImply provide concise, testable sample input and expected output that we could test a potential solution against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
function prt() {
    if ( prev != "" ) {
        for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {
            printf "%s%s", vals[i], (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
    delete vals
}

BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
$NF != prev { prt() }
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        vals[i] = (vals[i] ~ /[[:alpha:]]/ ? vals[i] : $i)
    }
    prev = $NF
}
END { prt() }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Person1,Person2,Person4,Person4,Person5,Person6,City
Yes,-,Yes,-,Yes,-,SanFrancisco
Yes,-,-,-,Yes,-,NewYork
-,-,-,-,-,Yes,Miami
```

The above assumes your input format is really a CSV like this:

```
$ cat file
Month,Person1,Person2,Person4,Person4,Person5,Person6,City
January,-,-,Yes,-,Yes,-,SanFrancisco
Febuary,Yes,-,-,-,-,-,SanFrancisco
March,-,-,-,-,-,-,SanFrancisco
April,-,-,-,-,-,-,NewYork
May,Yes,-,-,-,-,-,NewYork
June,-,-,-,-,-,-,NewYork
July,-,-,-,-,Yes,-,NewYork
August,-,-,-,-,-,-,NewYork
September,-,-,-,-,-,-,Miami
November,-,-,-,-,-,Yes,Miami
December,-,-,-,-,-,-,Miami
```

and you want a CSV output.

Comment: I seem to be getting : 


Person1,Person2,Person4,Person4,Person5,Person6,City

Yes,-,Yes,-,Yes,-,SanFrancisco

Yes,-,-,-,Yes,-,NewYork

-,-,-,-,-,Yes,Miami

-,-,-,-,-,-,Miami

(With Miami repeated twice)

Comment: @Tom then you're not running the script I posted on the input file I posted. Maybe you have a blank line at the end of your file? Maybe it contains control-Ms (`cat -v file` to check)? Edit your question to show the command you are running, the input file you're running it against and the output you are getting if you'd like more help.

Answer (score 2):

The proper term for what you're trying to do here is *aggregation*. The word *collapse* is not commonly used for this operation, in my experience.

I'm sort of learning python on-the-fly here, so there might be a better way, but I've gotten this to work using the [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) module, specifically the [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) type:

```
import pandas;
import re;

df = pandas.DataFrame({
    'Date':['January','Febuary','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','November','December'],
    'Person1':['-','Yes','-','-','Yes','-','-','-','-','-','-'],
    'Person2':['-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'],
    'Person3':['Yes','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'],
    'Person4':['-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'],
    'Person5':['Yes','-','-','-','-','-','Yes','-','-','-','-'],
    'Person6':['-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','Yes','-'],
    'City':['SanFrancisco','SanFrancisco','SanFrancisco','NewYork','NewYork','NewYork','NewYork','NewYork','Miami','Miami','Miami']
});

df.groupby('City').agg({k:lambda x: 'Yes' if 'Yes' in x.values else '-' for k in filter(lambda x:re.search(r'^Person',x),df.keys())});
##              Person2 Person3 Person1 Person6 Person4 Person5
## City
## Miami              -       -       -     Yes       -       -
## NewYork            -       -     Yes       -       -     Yes
## SanFrancisco       -     Yes     Yes       -       -     Yes
```

---

Also, I would highly recommend looking into the [R programming language](https://www.r-project.org/), which is an excellent and increasingly ubiquitous statistical, graphics, and general data analysis platform, which is perfect for working with Excel-style tabular data. These kinds of data format transformations are definitely more natural in R, although the learning curve is rather steep. Here's the R implementation:

```
df <- read.csv(stringsAsFactors=F,text=
'Date,Person1,Person2,Person3,Person4,Person5,Person6,City
January,-,-,Yes,-,Yes,-,SanFrancisco
Febuary,Yes,-,-,-,-,-,SanFrancisco
March,-,-,-,-,-,-,SanFrancisco
April,-,-,-,-,-,-,NewYork
May,Yes,-,-,-,-,-,NewYork
June,-,-,-,-,-,-,NewYork
July,-,-,-,-,Yes,-,NewYork
August,-,-,-,-,-,-,NewYork
September,-,-,-,-,-,-,Miami
November,-,-,-,-,-,Yes,Miami
December,-,-,-,-,-,-,Miami'
);

aggregate(.~City,df[-1L],function(x) if (any(x=='Yes')) 'Yes' else '-');
##           City Person1 Person2 Person3 Person4 Person5 Person6
## 1        Miami       -       -       -       -       -     Yes
## 2      NewYork     Yes       -       -       -     Yes       -
## 3 SanFrancisco     Yes       -     Yes       -     Yes       -
```

Comment: "Aggregate". I will remember that. Thank you!